# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file - <?php get_footer(); ?>

Tags: php

When I run this code, I get this error:

> **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/xx/public_html/wp-content/themes/template/index.php on line
>   418**
>   **index**

Here is this code:

```
<?php get_header(); $page = '';

$show_slideshow = get_option('show_slideshow');
$show_toppicks = get_option('show_toppicks');
$show_categories = get_option('show_categories');
$show_brands = get_option('show_brands');
$show_platforms = get_option('show_platforms');
$show_news = get_option('show_news');

if (!isset($_GET['s'])) {
if (substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"/page/") == 0 ) {
if (substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ,"/category/") == 0 && substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ,"/tag/") == 0 ) {
if ($show_slideshow == 1) {
?>
<div align='center' style='height:360px;'>
<img src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/title_box.png' border=0 style='margin-bottom:-83px;'>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i)){ } else {document.write('<div id="image-scroller-fx1">');}
</script>
<style>
.ascroll {float:left;position:relative;margin:0 0 18px2px;padding:0;border-radius:8px;-webkit-border-radius:8px;-moz-border-radius:8px;-o-border-radius:8px;-khtml-border-radius:8px;-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 1px 3px;-moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 1px 3px;background:#fff;-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 1px 3px;-moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 1px 3px;background:#fff;*border:1px solid;*border-color:#e5e5e5 #dbdbdb #d2d2d2;margin:7px;
}
</style>
<div style='margin-top:35px;margin-left:30px;'>
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("wp-content/plugins/image-scroller-fx/component/images.xml");
$datnum = substr_count("<photo",$data);
$url = get_bloginfo('url');
$datat = '';
for ($i=2;$i<=6;$i++) {
$dat = explode('<photo',$data);
$dat = explode('</photo>',$dat[$i]);
$dat = $dat[0];

$img = explode('image="',$dat);
$img = explode('"',$img[1]);
$img = $img[0];

$link = explode('url="',$dat);
$link = explode('"',$link[1]);
$link = $link[0];
$datat .= "<a href='$link'><img src='$url/wp-content/plugins/image-scroller-fx/component/$img' width='170px' class='ascroll'></a>";
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i)){document.write("<?=$datat;?>");}
</script>
</div>
</div><script type="text/javascript">swfobject.embedSWF('<?=$url?>/wp-content/plugins/image-scroller-fx/component/imagescroller.swf', 'image-scroller-fx1', '900', '330', '9.0.0.0', '', { folderPath: '<?=$url?>/wp-content/plugins/image-scroller-fx/component/' }, { scale: 'noscale', salign: 'tl', wmode: 'transparent', allowScriptAccess: 'sameDomain', allowFullScreen: true }, {});</script></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($show_toppicks == 1) { ?>
<table class="top" width="974" border="0" height="380px" align="center" style="margin-top:35px;">
  <tr>
    <td width="317" valign="top" background="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/box_of.gif"><div class="contentbox">
    <? include ("top1.txt"); ?>
    </div></td>
    <td width="317" valign="top" background="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/open_w.gif"><div class="contentbox">
      <? include ("top2.txt"); ?>
    </div></td>
    <td width="317" valign="top" background="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/coming_s.gif"><div class="contentbox">
      <? include ("top3.txt"); ?>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<? } } } } ?>
<?
$sectionURL=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/best-sellers") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=best-sellers") > 0) {$tags = "?tag=best-sellers";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/movers-shakers") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=movers-shakers") > 0) {$tags = "?tag=movers-shakers";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/most-wished-for") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=most-wished-for") > 0) {$tags = "?tag=most-wished-for";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/gift-ideas") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=gift-ideas") > 0) {$tags = "?tag=gift-ideas";}

if (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/pc") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"+pc") > 0  || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=pc") > 0) {$tags3 = "+pc";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/mac") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"+mac") > 0  || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=mac") > 0) {$tags3 = "+mac";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/nintendo-ds") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"+nintendo-ds") > 0  || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=nintendo-ds") > 0) {$tags3 = "+nintendo-ds";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/playstation-2") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"+playstation-2") > 0  || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=playstation-2") > 0) {$tags3 = "+playstation-2";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/playstation-3") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"+playstation-3") > 0  || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=playstation-3") > 0) {$tags3 = "+playstation-3";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/sony-psp") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"+sony-psp") > 0  || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=sony-psp") > 0) {$tags3 = "+sony-psp";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/wii") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"+wii") > 0  || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=wii") > 0) {$tags3 = "+wii";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/tag/xbox-360") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"+xbox-360") > 0  || substr_count($sectionURL,"tag=xbox-360") > 0) {$tags3 = "+xbox-360";}


if (substr_count($sectionURL,"pc/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"=pc")  > 0) {$c1 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"mac/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"=mac") > 0) {$c2 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"nintendo-ds/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"=nintendo-ds") > 0) {$c3 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"playstation-2/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"=playstation-2") > 0) {$c4 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"playstation-3/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"=playstation-3") > 0) {$c5 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"sony-psp/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"=sony-psp") > 0) {$c6 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"wii/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"=wii") > 0) {$c7 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"xbox-360/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"=xbox-360") > 0) {$c8 = "active";}

if (substr_count($sectionURL,"/action") > 0) {$cc1 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/adventure") > 0) {$cc2 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/arcade") > 0) {$cc3 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/puzzle") > 0) {$cc4 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/racing") > 0) {$cc5 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/role-playing") > 0) {$cc6 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/simulation") > 0) {$cc7 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/sports") > 0) {$cc8 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"/strategy") > 0) {$cc9 = "active";}

if (substr_count($sectionURL,"2k-games/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"2k-games+") > 0) {$c01 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"activision/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"activision+") > 0) {$c02 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"bethesda/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"bethesda+") > 0) {$c03 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"capcom/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"capcom+") > 0) {$c04 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"disney/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"disney+") > 0) {$c05 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"electronic-arts/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"electronic-arts+") > 0) {$c06 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"konami/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"konami+") > 0) {$c07 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"lucasarts/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"lucasarts+") > 0) {$c08 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"microsoft/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"microsoft+") > 0) {$c09 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"namco/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"namco+") > 0) {$c010 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"rockstar-games/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"rockstar-games+") > 0) {$c011 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"sega/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"sega+") > 0) {$c012 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"square-enix/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"square-enix+") > 0) {$c013 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"thq/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"thq+") > 0) {$c014 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"ubisoft/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"ubisoft+") > 0) {$c015 = "active";}
elseif (substr_count($sectionURL,"warner-bros/") > 0 || substr_count($sectionURL,"warner-bros+") > 0) {$c016 = "active";}

if (!empty($_GET['s'])) {$sh = '?s='.$_GET['s'];}
if (!empty($_GET['s']) && !empty($tags) && !empty($tags3)) {$sh = '&s='.$_GET['s'];}

?>
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-top:75px;margin-bottom:-45px;">
<?
if ($show_platforms == 1) {
if (!empty($tags)) {$tags2 = str_replace('?tag=','',$tags); $tags2 .= '+';}
if (!empty($sh2)) {$sh2 = '?s='.$_GET['s'];}
?>

<div id="content">

<nav>
<ul id="appleNav2">     
<li class="<?=$c1?>" style="width:104px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags2?>pc/<?=$sh2?>" title="PC Games">PC</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c2?>" style="width:100px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags2?>mac/<?=$sh2?>" title="Mac Games">Mac</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c3?>" style="width:135px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags2?>nintendo-ds/<?=$sh2?>" title="Nintendo DS Games">Nintendo DS</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c5?>" style="width:140px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags2?>playstation-3/<?=$sh2?>" title="PlayStation 3 Games">PlayStation 4 / PS3</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c4?>" style="width:140px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags2?>playstation-2/<?=$sh2?>" title="PlayStation 2 Games">PlayStation 2</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c6?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags2?>sony-psp/<?=$sh2?>" title="Sony PSP Games">Sony PSP</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c7?>" style="width:100px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags2?>wii/<?=$sh2?>" title="Wii Games">Wii</a></li>   
<li class="<?=$c8?>" style="width:125px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags2?>xbox-360/<?=$sh2?>" title="Xbox 360 Games">Xbox One / X360</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<?php }

if ($show_categories == 1) {
if (empty($tags)) {$tags3 = str_replace("+","?tag=",$tags3);}
?>
    <div id="content">

<nav>
<ul id="appleNav2">
<li class="<?=$cc1?>" style="width:110px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/action/<?=$tags?><?=$tags3?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Action Games">Action</a></li>
<li class="<?=$cc2?>" style="width:110px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/adventure/<?=$tags?><?=$tags3?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Adventure Games">Adventure</a></li>
<li class="<?=$cc3?>" style="width:100px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/arcade/<?=$tags?><?=$tags3?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Arcade Games">Arcade</a></li>
<li class="<?=$cc4?>" style="width:100px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/puzzle/<?=$tags?><?=$tags3?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Puzzle Games">Puzzle</a></li>
<li class="<?=$cc5?>" style="width:100px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/racing/<?=$tags?><?=$tags3?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Racing Games">Racing</a></li>
<li class="<?=$cc6?>" style="width:125px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/role-playing/<?=$tags?><?=$tags3?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Role-Playing Games">Role-Playing</a></li>
<li class="<?=$cc7?>" style="width:110px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/simulation/<?=$tags?><?=$tags3?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Simulation Games">Simulation</a></li>
<li class="<?=$cc8?>" style="width:100px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/sports/<?=$tags?><?=$tags3?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Sports Games">Sports</a></li>
<li class="<?=$cc9?>" style="width:101px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/strategy/<?=$tags?><?=$tags3?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Strategy Games">Strategy</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>

<?php
if ($show_brands == 1) {
$tags4 = $tags3;
if (empty($tags)) {$tags4 = str_replace("?tag=","+",$tags4);}
if (!empty($tags)) {$tags = str_replace('?tag=','',$tags); $tags .= '+';}
if (!empty($sh)) {$sh = '?s='.$_GET['s'];}
?>

<div id="wrapper" style="margin-top:75px;">
    <div id="content">

<nav>
<ul id="appleNav2">     
<li class="<?=$c01?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>2k-games<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by 2K Games">2K Games</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c02?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>activision<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Activision">Activision</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c03?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>bethesda<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Bethesda">Bethesda</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c04?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>capcom<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Capcom">Capcom</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c05?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>disney<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Disney">Disney</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c06?>" style="width:130px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>electronic-arts<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Electronic Arts">Electronic Arts</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c07?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>konami<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Konami">Konami</a></li>  
<li class="<?=$c08?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>lucasarts<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by LucasArts">LucasArts</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<div id="wrapper" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:-45px;">
<div id="content">

<nav>
<ul id="appleNav2">

<li class="<?=$c09?>" style="width:128px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>microsoft<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Microsoft">Microsoft</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c010?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>namco<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Namco">Namco</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c011?>" style="width:144px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>rockstar-games<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Rockstar Games">Rockstar Games</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c012?>" style="width:100px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>sega<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Sega">Sega</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c013?>" style="width:128px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>square-enix<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Square Enix">Square Enix</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c014?>" style="width:100px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>thq<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by THQ">THQ</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c015?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>ubisoft<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Ubisoft">Ubisoft</a></li>
<li class="<?=$c016?>" style="width:130px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tag/<?=$tags?>warner-bros<?=$tags4?>/<?=$sh?>" title="Games by Warner Bros">Warner Bros</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
<?php

}

 if (!isset($_GET['s'])) {
if (substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"/page/") == 0 ) {
if (substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ,"/category/") == 0 && substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ,"/tag/") == 0 ) {
?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bg_m.png" style='margin-top:25px;margin-left:-12px;margin-bottom:-17px;'>
        <div id="items" style=' margin-left:-2px; width:955px;height:286px;padding:15px;overflow:hidden; color:#808080; text-shadow:0 0 0 #000; background:#070707;  border-radius:12px; -webkit-border-radius:12px;margin-bottom:-317px; -moz-border-radius:12px; -o-border-radius:12px; -khtml-border-radius:12px;border:2px solid #090909;'>
</div>
<? } else {echo "<br><br>";?>       <div id="items" style=' margin-left:-2px; width:955px;height:286px;padding:15px;overflow:hidden; color:#808080; text-shadow:0 0 0 #000; background:#0c0c0c;  border-radius:12px; -webkit-border-radius:12px;margin-bottom:-317px; -moz-border-radius:12px; -o-border-radius:12px; -khtml-border-radius:12px;border:2px solid #161616;'>
</div><?} } else {echo "<br><br>";} } else {echo "<br><br>";} ?>
<div style='margin-left:0px;'>

<div id="items2">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$category = get_option('amazon_category');

if ($category != 'All Categories' && substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ,"/category/") == 0) {

switch ($category) {
                case "Games": $category="100";  break;
                case "Action": $category="101";     break;
                case "Adventure": $category="102";  break;
                case "Arcade": $category="103";     break;
                case "Board Games": $category="104";    break;
                case "Break Out": $category="105";  break;
                case "Cards": $category="106";  break;
                case "Casino": $category="107";     break;
                case "Flying": $category="108";     break;
                case "Free-to-Play Games": $category="109";     break;
                case "Mah Jong": $category="110";   break;
                case "Puzzle": $category="111";     break;
                case "Racing": $category="112";     break;
                case "Rhythm": $category="113";     break;
                case "Role-Playing": $category="114";   break;
                case "Seek & Find": $category="115";    break;
                case "Simulation": $category="116";     break;
                case "Sports": $category="117";     break;
                case "Strategy": $category="118";   break;
                case "Trivia": $category="119";     break;
                case "Video Cartridges": $category="120";   break;
                case "Word Games": $category="121";     break;
                case "Consoles": $category="122";   break;
                case "Accessories": $category="123";    break;
                case "Accessory Kits": $category="124";     break;
                case "Batteries &amp; Chargers": $category="125";   break;
                case "Cables &amp; Adapters": $category="126";  break;
                case "Cases &amp; Protectors": $category="127";     break;
                case "Controllers": $category="128";    break;
                case "Faceplates": $category="129";     break;
                case "Fitness Accessories": $category="130";    break;
                case "Gaming Keyboards": $category="131";   break;
                case "Gaming Mice": $category="132";    break;
                case "Headsets": $category="133";   break;
                case "Memory": $category="134";     break;
                case "Screen Protectors": $category="135";  break;
                case "Sensor Bars": $category="136";    break;
                case "Speakers": $category="137";   break;
                case "Skins": $category="138";  break;
                case "Networking": $category="139";     break;
                break;
                }

$catg = $category;
}

$version = get_option('amazon_locale');


switch ($version) {
                case "amazon.com": $version="142";  break;
                case "amazon.ca": $version="143";   break;
                case "amazon.co.uk": $version="144";    break;
                case "amazon.es": $version="145";   break;
                case "amazon.de": $version="146";   break;
                case "amazon.it": $version="147";   break;
                case "amazon.fr": $version="148";   break;
                case "amazon.cn": $version="149";   break;
                case "amazon.co.jp": $version="150";    break;
                break;
                }

$tagg = $version;

$type = get_option('amazon_type');

if ($type != '') {

switch ($type) {
                case "digital-downloads": $type="140";  break;
                case "physical-media": $type="141";     break;
                break;
                }

$type = '&tag__and='.$type;
}

$brand = get_option('amazon_brand');

if ($brand != '') {

switch ($brand) {
                case "2k-games": $brand="155";  break;
                case "activision": $brand="156";    break;
                case "bethesda": $brand="157";  break;
                case "capcom": $brand="158";    break;
                case "disney": $brand="159";    break;
                case "electronic-arts": $brand="160";   break;
                case "konami": $brand="161";    break;
                case "lucasarts": $brand="162";     break;
                case "microsoft": $brand="163";     break;
                case "namco": $brand="164";     break;
                case "rockstar-games": $brand="165";    break;
                case "sega": $brand="166";  break;
                case "square-enix": $brand="167";   break;
                case "thq": $brand="168";   break;
                case "ubisoft": $brand="169";   break;
                case "warner-bros": $brand="170";   break;
                break;
                }

$brand = '&tag_id='.$brand;
}

$platform = get_option('amazon_platform');
if ($platform != "All Platforms") 
{
$meta = "meta_key=platform&meta_value=$platform";
}

$query_string=$query_string."&cat=$catg&tag__in=$tagg$type$brand&$meta&paged=$page&showposts=20";
query_posts($query_string); ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="item">
        <div class="background"></div> 
        <div class=bg>
        <style>.item .bg:hover a img:hover{opacity:0.90;}</style>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class='imageOver' src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/zoom.gif' style='    position: absolute;
     top: -65px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 77px;
    height: 77px;border:0px;'></a>
        <?
        $bloginfo = get_bloginfo('url');
        the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        <h2 align="center"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php 
        the_title() 
        ?>
        </a></h2>
        <p align="center"><?php unset($previousday);the_date('d F Y','','');?></p>
        </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
    <div id="navi" style="margin-bottom:30px"><?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } ?>  </div>

</div>
<?php
if ($show_news == 1) {
?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div> 
<br><br>
<div style="float:left;margin-top:-50px;height:275px;">

<img src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/title_box2.png' border=0 style='margin-bottom:-78px;'>
        <div id="carousel-image-and-text" class="touchcarousel grey-blue">       
            <ul class="touchcarousel-container">
                <? include ("news.txt"); ?>
            </ul> 
        </div>
        <style>.inline {color:#bbb;}.inline2{color:#d4af04;}</style>
            <? include ("news-content.txt"); ?>

           <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({default_width:960,theme: 'dark_rounded'});
        });
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            jQuery("#carousel-image-and-text").touchCarousel({                  
                pagingNav: false,
                snapToItems: false,
                itemsPerMove: 5,                
                scrollToLast: false,
                loopItems: false,
                scrollbar: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

i check code in footer.php , but i don't see anythings
**footer**

```
<div id="globalfooter">

<p class="gf-buy"><a href="http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=sv_vg_5?ie=UTF8&node=2404622011&tag=<? echo get_option('amazon_associate');?>" target="_blank">Which Console Is Right For You?</a> </p>

<ul class="gf-links piped">
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/terms-of-use/" class="first">Terms of Use</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>">RSS Feeds</a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:<?php bloginfo('admin_email');?>" class="contact_us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="gf-sosumi">
    <p><center>Copyright &copy; 2012 <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - All rights reserved.</center></p>
    <p><center>The owner of this website is a participant in the Amazon Services LLC Associates Program, an affiliate advertising program designed to provide a means for sites to earn advertising fees by advertising and linking to <? echo get_option("amazon_locale");?>. Kindle, Kindle Fire and Amazon are trademarks of Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates.</center></p>
</div>

</div>
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("TRACKING CODE") ) : ?> <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me, what's wrong with this code?

Comment: What does this line do? <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("TRACKING CODE") ) : ?> <?php endif; ?>

Comment: can we have the original file of `index.php` before you modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your [short_open_tag](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) setting (use `<?php phpinfo() ?>` to see its current setting).